# Set cell color based on current value

Tags: excel, vba

How can my code be made shorter?

If a user fills the cell with color yellow then if its value is 0 then it will turn to red and it will popup a message box, then if its value is > 0 it will back again to yellow, then if the user enters value of > 0 in the "no fill up cell" it will turn grey and back to no fill up if I input 0 this code is for column L only I need to make this for column M, N and O also.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    On Error GoTo ExitSub

    'WEEK 0
    'For Task Not done
    With ws.Cells(15, 12)
        If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("L15"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
            If .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And .Value < 1 Then  
                MsgBox "Project Delay!"
                Range("L15").Interior.ColorIndex = 3  
            Else
                If Range("L15").Interior.ColorIndex = 3 And .Value > 0 Then
                    Range("L15").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            End If

            'For overlapped Task
            If .Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 And .Value > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Overlap!"
                Range("L15").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
            Else
                If Range("L15").Interior.ColorIndex = 16 And .Value < 1 Then
                    Range("L15").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With

    On Error GoTo ExitSub

    'For Task Not done
    With ws.Cells(17, 12)
        If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("L17"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
            If .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And .Value < 1 Then
                MsgBox "Project Delay!"
                Range("L17").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                If Range("L17").Interior.ColorIndex = 3 And .Value > 0 Then
                    Range("L17").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            End If

            'For overlapped Task
            If .Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 And .Value > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Overlap!"
                Range("L17").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
            Else
                If Range("L17").Interior.ColorIndex = 16 And .Value < 1 Then
                    Range("L17").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. As far as I understood your intentions it should do what you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Tmp As Long

    With Target
        If .Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If (.Column >= Columns("L").Column) And (.Column <= .Columns("O").Column) Then
            Tmp = Val(.Value)
            Select Case .Row
                Case 15
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(Tmp, 6, 3)
                    If Tmp = 0 Then
                        MsgBox "Project Delay!", _
                               vbCritical, "Attention required!"
                    End If
                Case 17
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(Tmp, 16, -4142)
                    If Tmp Then
                        MsgBox "Enter a value of zero.", _
                               vbExclamation, "Overlap!"
                    End If
            End Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I have kept the syntax simple so that you ought to be able to tweak it where it needs tweaking. Good luck!